# Max(ID) of each table on a database

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to get the maximum value **MAX(ID)** for each table I have which contains ID on my DB *"Table_Example"* and one schema_name in specific.

A single example:

```
SELECT MAX(ID) FROM Schema_name.Table_name1
```

This retrieve the maximum ID value that is located on Table_name1, but I have 84 tables. I would like to know the max of each table only in one column.
This is the code where I am working on currently:
I am using **information_schema.columns** to get the names of the tables automatic and the schema each table belongs to in order to get the whole DB IDs max(id) in one column.

```
USE TABLE_EXAMPLE
GO
DECLARE @ID NVARCHAR(MAX) --int

SET @ID = (SELECT DISTINCT COLUMN_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'SCHEMA_NAME' AND COLUMN_NAME IN ('ID') AND DATA_TYPE = 'INT')

SELECT @ID FROM (SELECT ('SCHEMA_NAME'+'.'+TABLE_NAME) AS TABLE_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'SCHEMA_NAME' AND COLUMN_NAME = 'ID' AND DATA_TYPE='INT') AS W
```

This Script retrieve wrong data but I think I am a bit closed to get the values, but I am not sure what I am doing wrong.
Could someone give me any good approach? Or any better option to get it done?

Comment: Is the column name `ID` in every table?

Comment: Are you simply trying to get the max value of the identity/index column in each of your tables?

Comment: @JohnPasquet and yet you managed to post an answer.. Give OP some time. Not everybody is on SO all the time

Comment: @TimCastelijns He's new.  Just trying to give some helpful advice.  And still no answers.

Comment: @JohnPasquet Sorry, yesterday I was unable to write. Answering your question I am just trying to get the max value of ID column on each table on my DB where exists ID colunm. I need this because I am using a Table call e.g.(ID_sequence_table) which posses the name and the next maximum value of each ID column for each table. Then I would like to do an Update/insert starting from this values I would like to retrieve.

Comment: @Fmanin would you please stop adding the tsql-tag to questions where it is just plain wrong (like those tagged mysql or oracle)? You should only add it where it is obviously right (questions concerning sql-server or those using specific tsql-syntax).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This enumerate all tables with column Id and MAX value of this ID:

```
DECLARE @query nvarchar(MAX);
SELECT @query = COALESCE(@query + char(10)+'UNION ALL '+char(10)+'SELECT '''+QUOTENAME(s.name)+'.'+QUOTENAME(T.name)+''' [Table], MAX(Id) [Max] FROM '+QUOTENAME(s.name)+'.'+QUOTENAME(T.name),
'SELECT '''+QUOTENAME(s.name)+'.'+QUOTENAME(T.name)+''' [Table], MAX(Id) [Max] FROM '+QUOTENAME(s.name)+'.'+QUOTENAME(T.name))
FROM sys.schemas S
JOIN sys.tables T ON S.schema_id=T.schema_id
JOIN sys.columns C ON T.object_id=C.object_id
WHERE C.name='Id';
EXEC(@query);
```

Answer (score 6):

If you are wanting the max value in your identity columns, regardless of the names of those columns, then this is a very simple way of doing it.  This will give you the Table Name, the name of the Identity Column, and the max value of that column:

```
SELECT sys.tables.name AS [Table Name], 
    sys.identity_columns.name AS [Column Name],
    last_value AS [Last Value]      
FROM sys.identity_columns
    INNER JOIN sys.tables
        ON sys.identity_columns.object_id = sys.tables.object_id
ORDER BY last_value DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this,

This would give you the script.

```
SELECT DISTINCT 'SELECT MAX(' + + COLUMN_NAME + ') as ' + table_name + 'MaxId FROM ' + table_name
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'dbo'
    AND COLUMN_NAME IN ('ID')
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps a little dynamic SQL

> **Edit**  This will return the Table Name(s) and Max ID in one dataset

```
Declare @SQL varchar(max) = '>>>'
Select @SQL = @SQL + SQL
 From (
        Select SQL='Union All Select TableName='''+concat('[',Table_Schema,'].[',Table_Name,']')+''',MaxID=max(ID) From '+concat('[',Table_Schema,'].[',Table_Name,'] ') 
          From INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
          Where Column_Name = 'ID'
      ) A

Set @SQL=Replace(@SQL,'>>>Union All ','')
Exec(@SQL)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE #MaxValues (SchemaName SYSNAME , TableName SYSNAME , MaxID INT)
GO


Declare @SchemaName SYSNAME = 'dbo'  --<-- Pass you schema name to this variable
       ,@ColumnName SYSNAME = 'ID'   --<-- Column Name
       ,@DataType   SYSNAME = 'INT'  --<-- Data type 



DECLARE @TableName SYSNAME , @SchmaName SYSNAME
      , @Sql NVARCHAR(MAX) , @ColName SYSNAME;

Declare Cur CURSOR LOCAL FAST_FORWARD FOR
SELECT s.name , t.name , c.name 
FROM sys.columns c 
Inner join sys.tables t  on c.object_id = t.object_id
Inner join sys.schemas s on s.schema_id = t.schema_id
Inner join sys.types tp  on tp.user_type_id = c.user_type_id
WHERE s.name = @SchemaName
 AND  c.name = @ColumnName
 AND  tp.name = @DataType

OPEN Cur 
  FETCH NEXT FROM Cur INTO @SchmaName , @TableName , @ColName

WHILE (@@FETCH_STATUS =0)
BEGIN
   SET @Sql = N'INSERT INTO #MaxValues (SchemaName, TableName, MaxID )'
           +  N' SELECT @SchmaName ,@TableName,  MAX(' + QUOTENAME(@ColName) + N') '
           +  N' FROM ' + QUOTENAME(@SchmaName) + '.' + QUOTENAME(@TableName) 

    Exec sp_executesql @Sql 
                      ,N'@SchmaName SYSNAME , @TableName SYSNAME'
                      ,@SchmaName
                      ,@TableName
     FETCH NEXT FROM Cur INTO @SchmaName , @TableName , @ColName
END

CLOSE Cur 
DEALLOCATE Cur 

SELECT * FROM #MaxValues
```

Answer (score 0):

This script will list all the max ids. It is assuming your first column is the ID, regardless of its name.

```
DECLARE @Script AS VARCHAR(MAX) = ''

SELECT @Script = @Script + 'SELECT MAX(' + COLUMN_NAME + ') AS ID FROM ' + c.TABLE_NAME + '  UNION ALL ' + CHAR(13)+CHAR(10)
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS c
INNER JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES t ON c.TABLE_NAME = t.TABLE_NAME
WHERE c.ORDINAL_POSITION = 1 and t.TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE' and c.TABLE_SCHEMA = 'dbo' and c.DATA_TYPE = 'int'

SELECT @Script = LEFT(@Script, LEN(@Script) - 12)

EXEC (@Script)
```